# Steam installation, libudev1:i386 cannot be installed without removing a lot of other packages

Tags: apt, steam

I am trying to install steam with this command:

```
# apt install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 steam:i386 : Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 17.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                       libtxc-dxtn0:i386 but it is not installable
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: nvidia-driver-libs-i386:i386 but it is not installable
```

So I tried to install manually `libudev1:i386` :

```
apt download libudev1:i386
# dpkg -i --force-all libudev1_237-3ubuntu10_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package libudev1:i386.
(Reading database ... 171004 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libudev1_237-3ubuntu10_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libudev1:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.3) ...
Unpacking libudev1:i386 (237-3ubuntu10) ...
dpkg: error processing package libudev1:i386 (--install):
 package libudev1:i386 237-3ubuntu10 cannot be configured because libudev1:amd64 is at a different version (237-3ubuntu10.3)
dpkg: error processing package libudev1:amd64 (--install):
 package libudev1:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.3 cannot be configured because libudev1:i386 is at a different version (237-3ubuntu10)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libudev1:i386
 libudev1:amd64
```

Here are the policy differences :

```
# apt-cache policy libudev1:i386 libudev1
libudev1:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 237-3ubuntu10
  Version table:
     237-3ubuntu10 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
libudev1:
  Installed: 237-3ubuntu10.3
  Candidate: 237-3ubuntu10.3
  Version table:
 *** 237-3ubuntu10.3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     237-3ubuntu10 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
N: Ignoring file 'google-chrome.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

I tried installing the package with apt but it seems I have to remove so many package to do it :

```
# apt install libudev1:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aptitude-common dkms libbsd0:i386 libcwidget3v5 libffi6:i386 libnvidia-cfg1-390 libnvidia-common-390 libnvidia-compute-390 libnvidia-compute-390:i386 libnvidia-decode-390 libnvidia-decode-390:i386
  libnvidia-encode-390 libnvidia-encode-390:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-390 libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-390 libsigc++-2.0-0v5 libvdpau1 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-server0:i386
  libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxnvctrl0 mesa-vdpau-drivers nvidia-compute-utils-390 nvidia-dkms-390 nvidia-kernel-common-390 nvidia-kernel-source-390 nvidia-prime
  nvidia-utils-390 pkg-config shim vdpau-driver-all
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  alsa-base apport apport-gtk apt apt-utils aptdaemon aptitude apturl apturl-common bluez bluez-cups bolt brltty code colord command-not-found cups dbus-user-session dmsetup dosfstools eject eog evince
  evolution-data-server file-roller firefox friendly-recovery fuse fwupd gcr gdm3 gedit gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-mutter-2 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gjs gkbd-capplet gnome-bluetooth
  gnome-control-center gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-getting-started-docs-fr gnome-initial-setup gnome-keyring gnome-online-accounts gnome-power-manager gnome-screenshot
  gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-snap gnome-startup-applications gnome-terminal gnome-user-docs gnome-user-docs-fr
  gnome-user-guide google-chrome-stable grub-common grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-gl
  gstreamer1.0-packagekit gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse hplip ibus ibus-gtk3 ibus-table iio-sensor-proxy init initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core
  ippusbxd language-selector-common language-selector-gnome libappindicator3-1 libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg-perl libapt-pkg5.0 libatasmart4 libblockdev-crypto2 libblockdev-fs2 libblockdev-loop2 libblockdev-part2
  libblockdev-swap2 libblockdev-utils2 libblockdev2 libbluetooth3 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-3.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcolord-gtk1 libcolord2 libcolorhug2 libcryptsetup12 libdazzle-1.0-0 libdevmapper1.02.1 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3 libfreerdp-client2-2 libgail-3-0
  libgcr-ui-3-1 libgjs0g libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-desktop-3-17 libgnomekbd8 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-port12 libgpod-common libgspell-1-1 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
  libgtk3-perl libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2 libgweather-3-15 libhpmud0 libindicator3-7 libinput-bin libinput10 libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libmutter-2-0
  libnautilus-extension1a libnm0 libnma0 libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libparted-fs-resize0 libparted2 libpci3 libpeas-1.0-0 libplymouth4 libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libsane-hpaio libsane1 libsnmp30 libudev1
  libusb-1.0-0 libvolume-key1 libvte-2.91-0 libwacom-bin libwacom2 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwnck-3-0 libyelp0 lintian media-player-info modemmanager mount mousetweaks mutter nautilus
  nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal nautilus-share netplan.io network-manager network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome
  notification-daemon nplan ntfs-3g nvidia-driver-390 nvidia-settings orca os-prober packagekit packagekit-tools parted pciutils pinentry-gnome3 plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text policykit-1 printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-splix pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth python3-apport python3-apt
  python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-commandnotfound python3-distupgrade python3-software-properties python3-update-manager rtkit sane-utils screen-resolution-extra seahorse shim-signed
  snapd software-properties-common software-properties-gtk system-config-printer system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-udev systemd systemd-sysv sysvinit-utils ubuntu-docs ubuntu-drivers-common
  ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-session ubuntu-software ubuntu-standard ubuntu-system-service udev udisks2 unattended-upgrades upower usb-creator-common usb-modeswitch usbmuxd usbutils
  util-linux whoopsie xdg-user-dirs-gtk xorg xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390 xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-radeon
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware yelp zenity
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libudev1:i386
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt libapt-pkg5.0 (due to apt) init systemd-sysv (due to init) mount util-linux (due to mount) sysvinit-utils libudev1 (due to util-linux)
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 281 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 57,0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1 029 MB disk space will be freed.
N: Ignoring file 'google-chrome.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
You are about to do something potentially harmful
To continue type in the phrase ‘Yes, do as I say!’
```

I am not sure how to proceed since libudev:amd seems to be used by almost all the system.

Comment: What OS are you using?  and what release?   I get the feeling you've mixed releases of Ubuntu in your system or aren't running Ubuntu (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libudev1  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libgl1-mesa-dri and others I picked at random) make some of your package versions look like 16.04, others like 18.04.

Comment: Sorry I should have given this info in the post, I am using the Ubuntu 18.04 adm64 desktop image I downloaded from the website.

Comment: My sources.list just contain bionic packages for main universe restricted multiverse and partner

Answer (score 0):

displaying the log file `/var/log/aptitude` showed held packages, when removed I could install steam without any problem